# How do I plot the root locus when there are multiple controller gains?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, root-locus

I am trying to design a closed loop system with a PI controller. I have plotted root loci before, but in those, I had assumed that the controller was only Proportional. This gave a characteristic equation of the form:

```
1 + K*(n(s)/d(s)) = 0
```

where K is the proportional controller gain, which was varied to plot the root locus.

However, with a PI controller, there are two gains Kp and Ki, so how do I plot the root locus since both of them can be varied?

Comment: If you were going to draw a block diagram of a PI controller, what would it look like? Could you use properties of control block diagrams to reduce any equations? (I’m asking these questions to you as hints)

Comment: **1**) What do you think the resulting locus will look like and **2**) how are you planning to use it for design?

Comment: Are you going to use software to plot the locus(numerical)? Or manually on own and paper(analytical expression)?

Comment: You could fix one and plot the locus of the other, then repeat.